# How to stop all search engines, bots to crawl some urls

Tags: search, search-engine, bots, search-engine-bots

I want to count ads click on a widget.

I've used on robot.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: */ads_count/*
```

I've also add `nofollow` for all links in that widget.

But many bots still follow urls in that widget. I've get client ip to count urls and i got many IP form bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u try removing the (*) before */ads_count?
As google documentation for SEO says, if you want to block all the bots, it's like u did:

```
User-agent: * // (to whom? (*) means all bots!
Disallow: /ads_count
```

> Note that directives are case-sensitive. For instance, Disallow: /junk_file.asp would block http://www.example.com/junk_file.asp, but would allow http://www.example.com/Junk_file.asp. Googlebot will ignore white-space (in particular empty lines)and unknown directives in the robots.txt.

Comment: Ex for my url: http://www.abc.com/ads_count/?u=213&a=9

So i try to disallow all bots follow all URLs */ads_count/*
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try adding User-agent: *
Disallow: /ads_count*/ (it's supposed to block all sub directories from ads_count

Comment: take a look at this: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=pt-BR&answer=156449

Comment: usually it was supposed to be ok, the way u did.  How ru testing it?

Answer (score 0):

`Allow` and the wildcard `*` in `Disallow` are not part of the original robots.txt specification, so not all robots.txt parsers will know/note those rules.

If you want to block all pages starting with `/ads_count/`, you just need:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ads_count/
```

However: not all bots respect robots.txt. So you'd still get hits by bad bots that ignore robots.txt.